# How to completely shift execution control from one interactive function to the other in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, synchronous

I have two functions to accept input from the CLI using **process.stdin**. When one of the function is completed accepting input data, similar such function is invoked but when the control is shifted to the called function, calling function is still been referred and executed which is generating contradicting results.

```
var ar = [];
var a = 0;

test();

function test2(){
    console.log("TEst 2");
    process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
    process.stdin.resume();
    process.stdin.on('data',function(b){
        if(ar.length < a)
        {
            ar.push(b.replace("\n",""));
        }
        else
        {
            test3();
        }
    });
}

function test3()
{
    for(var t in ar)
   {
       console.log("ar["+t+"]: " + ar[t]);
   }
   process.exit();
}

function test()
{
    process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
    process.stdin.resume();
    process.stdin.on('data',function(dat)
    {
              dat = dat.replace("\n","");
              if(isNaN(dat))
              {
                console.log("This is an invalid number");
              }
              else
              {
                a = parseInt(dat);
                console.log("calling test2");
                 test2();
              }
    });
}
```

`test()` invokes `test2()`. Everytime the data is accepted in `test2()`, this data is validated for `isNaN` in `test()` and produces `console.log("This is an invalid number");` for any non-numeric input which is a valid data.
Please find the result below.

```
deepakbilikere:~/workspace $ node goodnumber.js 
2
calling test2
TEst 2
a
This is an invalid number
b
This is an invalid number
c
This is an invalid number
ar[0]: a
ar[1]: b
```

**I would like to execute this piece of logic without the use of any external packages.**
Can someone please help me in understanding the code flow as well as improve the code??

Answer (score 0):

One thing that pops out immediately, is that you're attaching multiple  listeners to the `data` event for `stdin`. Note that the previous listener in `test()` doesn't go anywhere while your attaching a second one in `test2()`. You could achieve some improvements by using `once()` that only listens to the event one time and then unregisters itself. But you have to be careful how the stream resuming behaves then (research this).

```
process.stdin.once('data', ...)
```

Also, can you tell us what is it that you're aiming to do, so we can help you better. Now the goal gets lost in the midst of nested functions.

Comment: Thank you @pspi.
Stream resume seems to be behaving fine. My concern here was why was that the `test()` stream still referred when `test2()` was already invoked. Your answer addressed my concern.
However my primary objective was to achieve this [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892588/synchronous-code-execution-in-nodejs-with-the-reuse-of-a-function-accepting-inpu). Since I didnt get any solution to this I retorted to above method.